# $\overline H$ is a normal subgroup of a topological group $G$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

**Let $G$ be a topological group. How can we prove that if $H$ is a normal  subgroup of $G$, then $\overline H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ also?**

First of all, we have to prove that $\overline H$ is a subgroup of $G$, that is easy, I'm having problems to prove that $\overline H$ is normal.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $H$ is invariant under conjugation and the topology is invariant under conjugation, the result follows.

Comment: can you write the details please?

Comment: what do you mean by the topology is invariant under conjugation?

Comment: @Rafael A conjugate of an open set is also an open set.